# Как реализовать поддержку якорей на AJAX сайте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!

Строю веб-сайт на основе одностраничного AJAX шаблона:
http://www.templatemo.com/tm-398-nature

В данном шаблоне широко используется Javascript, в частности применяется библиотека Jquery. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: При навигации по сайту адресная строка остается без изменений. Не могу дать прямую ссылку на конкретную секцию сайта.

Прошу поделится опытом в вопросе навигации на AJAX сайтах.

Comment: копай в сторону  `pjax`. [к примеру отсюда](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) ... по сайту бегать можно через `ajax` при этом и ссылки будут нужные.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Если взять во внимание заголовок вопроса, то там указано `якорей`. Насколько я помню, `pjax` не поддерживает якоря (fallback для старых браузеров), а только `pushState()` - личное предпочтение автора `pjax`.

Comment: @Роман: Если вы решили следовать [SPA-way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), то стоит обратить внимание на SPA-фреймворки (Angular, Ember, Knockout и др.) с маршрутизацией и остальными плюшкми. И почитате про [`pushState()`](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/) от Михаила Давыдова (бывший сотрудник yandex).

Comment: @romeo В заголовке, конечно, написано якоря, но, судя по телу сообщения, в принципе, якоря не обязательны. Потому, что суть проблемы  в другом: в неизменности адресной строки, при динамической загрузке контента. Эту проблему с лихвой решает `pjax`. Если уж тааак сильно хочется якоря (хотя непонятно зачем, если в строке они все равно не должны быть видны) есть форки `pjax'a` на гитхабе, где есть поддержка якорей......Однако если проще написать функционал основанный на `pushState` вместо готового, и якоря позарез нужны, то да - можно пушстейтиться)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. заголовок темы немного не соответствует телу сообщения, то попробую обобщить и то и другое.

Если вы хотите действительно использовать якоря, в том числе необходимо, чтобы они были в адресной строке, т.е. вид был типа:
`http://mysite.ru/#users`, то вы можете воспользоваться `API` для работы с историей в браузере. В частности вам понадобиться метод `pushState`
Подробнее можно ознакомиться с ним на [например тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Если же вам, судя из самого сообщения, необходимо именно именно наличие ссылок в адресной строке, к которым было сделано обращение, то попробуйте ознакомиться с `pjax (pushState + ajax)`. Он как раз включает в себя работу с `history API` и вам не придется брать на себя работу с логикой истории.
Контент будет браться также  через `ajax`, при этом и ссылки будут нужные.

Один из вариантов находится [ТУТ](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)

Конкретно **данный** вариант pjax'a не работает с якорями.
Если вам лень **и** делать логику на основе `history API` самому **и** в то же время нужны якоря, то есть различного рода форки от `pjax` которые допускают поддержку хеш-навигации, например [вот этот](https://github.com/ckald/jquery-pjax)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, использовать специальную форму записи якорей, и подхватывать JS-ом.

Например ссылки вида: `site.ru/#about, site.ru/#contacts` - осуществляют переходы по страницам.
А ссылки вида, скажем: `site.ru/#about:ancor_1` и так далее распознаются JS-ом, как адрес с дополнительным параметром, который вызывает например функцию плавной прокрутки до нужного якоря.